# Integration over the height of the function

Tags: integration

I am currently reading a proof where the author uses the following equality.
$$\int_0^1g(t)^rdt=r\int_0^\infty\vert\{g>u\}\vert u^{r-1}du$$
Here, $g$ is some positive measurable function and $r$ is a positive real number. I would be happy if someone could explain or prove that to me, or tell me how this equality is called, if it has a name.

Comment: It's common in probability, I don't know if it has any names though. [See here for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value).

Comment: [This is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260157/moments-of-a-random-variable-in-terms-of-its-cumulative-distribution-function).